# How can I force Player 2 to leave the session?

Tags: lego-lord-of-the-rings

After playing a session with two people (after pressiong F2 to enable them) and I don't want them to play any more, how can I get them to leave the session so their player goes back to CPU control? I've tried pressing F2 again for them to leave, and that doesn't work. Only quitting and then re-lanching the game seems to work, but this isn't the right way to do it...is it?

Comment: I'm not sure about the PC version, but on Xbox, if player 2 pauses the game they have an option to leave the game.

Comment: Since it has local coop only - punch him in the face?

Comment: ^ best answer/comment ever

Comment: I think chargingpun has it: whatever the keypress is to pause the game for the player who is leaving (prob enter & numpad enter), press it, and then select the option to leave (drop out??).

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness, if it was my brother I was playing with, no problem. As it's my Dad I'm trying to poke back towards games...not such a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

ChargingPun and horatio are correct. To drop out, have the keyboard player pause the game (the default key is <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the numeric keypad) and choose Drop Out from the menu.